# NPM command Nothing showing up

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, npm-install

When I type NPM commands like npm install , npm config, npm start 
nothing is showing up in cmd or gitbash just its blank neither showing error nor anything

i already cleared cache by deleting every folders inside the cache

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot please?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound like a helpdesk answer but perhaps it would help.

1. Ensure that you are running npm from the directory you installed it to. (If your path isn't right, you should get a "not a program" message).
2. Ensure that NPM is in your path
3. Ensure that you installed NPM with Admin rights
4. ... you are going to love this... reboot your machine... :)
5. If none of the above works, un-install it, and then re-install it...

If you can provide a screenshot that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Check your npm or nodejs versions if they exist, by typing these 2 commands in your terminal

```
node -v
npm -v
```

then if one of them doesn't exist try to reinstall node JS https://nodejs.org/en/download/